# What should basically public folder contain in React

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and came across public folder which contains html file, favicon and the others. The question is for what public folder is actually created? and what should it contain?

Comment: I am assuming you're using `create-react-app` - it's in the docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just static contents that do not need to compile (.html, .svg, .jpg, ...).

Just like `www` folder for **ASP.net Core** projects.

But It is your desition to put them there or somewhere else.

[Documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)

Answer (score 0):

React is a JavaScript library that needs to be "compiled" into code that the browser understands, so the `public` or `build` or `dist` folders are for holding the output of the compilation process or if you'd like, they store your artifact.

Just like `target` folder for Java projects.